# Which row/column in a matrix genarate which singular value

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I know that svd of a matrix arranges the singular values in descending order. My question is:
Is it possible to know which row/column generate a specific singular value, for e.g. the largest one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SVD is usually written with the singular values in decreasing order, but this is not “compelling”.

Comment: The idea is to know which row and column of matrix which generate the largest singular value. The largest singular value and its corresponding singularvectors contain the most important information.